# how to merge changes from original project -- GitHub in Windows

Tags: windows, git, github

I created an account at https://github.com/, fork someone's project so I have my own repository, instal github client for windows, and clone my repository to my local drive.

I will work on my local drive. But during the developement of the project, I would like to merge the changes in the official, original, project.

I didn't find how to do this. Before, I use tortoiseSVN client for windows, and there is an option "SVN Update" which can update the project to the latest revision. But I am new to Github and its client, and don't know how to do it.

Comment: which client are you using?

Comment: I download the client here,  http://windows.github.com/, I thought it is the official client?

Comment: that it is, but it's pretty limited - are you looking to merge changes *to* the original project or *from* the original project?

Comment: merge changes from the original project to my own repository

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The GitHub for Windows client does not support having multiple remotes[[1]](http://windows.github.com/help.html), which is required in order to sync a forked repo with an upstream repository.  You'll have to drop to the command line to perform the update.  GitHub has some nice instructions in [their documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo) which I'll summarize:

Once you have your local repo, add a new "upstream" remote:

```
git remote add upstream <path to upstream repo>
```

Now fetch the upstream repo to get the newest updates (not merged to your local repo yet)

```
git fetch upstream
```

Now merge in the upstream changes

```
git merge upstream/master
```

Comment: It should be noted it might be feasible to rebase your commits if you didn't push them yet.

Comment: well, you beat me to it :-) alternatively, a git pull will do the fetch + merge

Comment: so "path to upstream repo" is the original project repository, not my own folked repository?

Comment: @user62046 That is correct, you'll add a remote reference the original repo and merge changes from there, then you can push the changes you make back to your personal fork on Github.

Comment: @heavyd, thanks. Just a final question: When I folked the original project, I get a master branch. And I created a new branch, say "branch_1". When I do the above commands, which one is updated? If I want to update only one of these two branch, how can I specify which one to be updated? (In tortoiseSVN, I can switch between branches)

Comment: @user62046, that is more of a fundamental git usage question, so I would recommend checking out the [git documentation on branching](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching), but to answer your question just change the "master" in the merge command to which ever branch you want to update, so to update "branch_1" run `git merge upstream/branch_1`